# How to play a video frame by frame using vitamio player or by using native player?

Tags: ios, video, vitamio

Actually , I Want to play a video frame by frame. So When video is pause and slider is drag to new position then that position frame is to be displayed .Means frame to be changed either video is in pause state.

Any clue may be Helpful for me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you find a way to do this?

Comment: Are you delivering the videos or do you want to play any video?